# How can I show only 5 posts from the relationship?

Tags: query-posts

**HI**
I use plugin: Advanced Custom Fields

How can I show only 5 posts from the relationship?

This is the code:

```
<?php $c_lists = get_field( 'c_lists' ); ?>
<?php if ( $c_lists ) : ?>
    <?php foreach ( $c_lists as $post_ids ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_ids ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $post_ids ); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the key from the foreach

```
<?php
$c_lists = get_field('c_lists');
if ($c_lists) :
    foreach ($c_lists as $key => $post_ids) :
    if ($key > 4) break;
?>
<a href="<?= get_permalink($post_ids); ?>"><?= get_the_title($post_ids); ?></a>
<?php
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: This works fine thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

You can follow such a path

```
<?php if ( $c_lists ) : ?>
    <?php $max = 5; $start = 0; foreach ( $c_lists as $post_ids ) : 
    $start++; 
    if( $start >= $max ) break;
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_ids ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $post_ids ); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That works too, thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option: you can [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) the array you pass into the foreach

```php
<?php $c_lists = get_field( 'c_lists' ); ?>
<?php if ( $c_lists ) : ?>
    <?php foreach ( $c_lists as array_slice( $post_ids, 0, 5 ) ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_ids ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $post_ids ); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```